# Почему не выполняется код в executeScript?

Tags: javascript, расширения

Функция parse не запускается, либо запускается, но ничего не делает. В чем проблема?

Манифест:

```
{
    "name": "Парсер для списка слов на learngerman.dw",
    "description": "Возвращает список слов для приложения ReWord",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "32": "favicon32.png"
        },
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "scripting",
        "activeTab",
        "storage"
    ]
}
```

Скрипт:

```
const butt = document.getElementById("startButt");

butt.addEventListener("click", async () => {
    let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: { tabId: tab.id },
        function: parse,
    })
});

function parse() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    
    let message = document.createElement("div");
    message.style.position = "absolute";
    message.style.background = "white";
    if (document.location.href.indexOf("learngerman.dw") != -1) {

    } else {

    }
}
```

popup:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
    <button id="startButt">Спарсить</button>
    <script src="background.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте заменить

```
function: parse
```

на:

```
func: parse
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).